# How to accept a function reference as an argument?

Tags: c#, .net, function, byref

I'm currently passing a `EventHandler` object to a util function like this:

```
Timer newTimer(int interval, System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler handler) {
    ....
    timer.Elapsed += handler;
    ....
}

newTimer(1000, new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(myTimer_Tick));
```

But this is ugly and forces every caller to create an `EventHandler` object. How do I change that to something like this?

```
Timer newTimer(int interval, ref Function handler) {
    ....
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(handler);
    ....
}

newTimer(1000, ref myTimer_Tick);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear why you're using `ref` here, but if `myTimer_Tick` has the right signature, you don't need to change your method at all - you can just use:

```
newTimer(1000, myTimer_Tick);
```

This uses a method group conversion instead an explicit delegate creation statement. It does the same thing though.

If you want to be able to use parameterless void methods, you could write a helper method to take an `Action` and wrap that in an `ElapsedEventHandler` via a lambda expression:

```
Timer StartTimer(int interval, Action action)
{
    ...
    timer.Elapsed = (sender, args) => action();
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Geotarget: if that works for you, why haven't you marked it as an answer to your question?

Comment: Because SO now has a 10 minute timer before you can mark an answer.

Comment: @Geotarget: ok, thanks for letting me know. I was just curious why it was not marked when you already stated that it works. I see quite often that people tend to lose interest in marking proper answer as soon as they can move forward with the code (which is pretty unfair for those trying to help).